# "Привет воинам-освободителям от немецко-фашистских захватчиков!"

Tags: стилистика

Эта фраза как-то попалась в "Нарочно не придумаешь". Звучит смешно, но как ее переформулировать, чтобы звучало здраво?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А никак не переделать, только заново написать, примерно как Валентин предлагает, но тогда теряется вся лозунговость фразы, причастные обороты, тем более - подчиненные предложения, тому никак не способствуют... 
А проблема в том, что "освободитель от чего" изначально не несет в себе ничего кроме подобных недоразумений.

Answer (score 4):

Во избежание двусмысленности в этом предложении достаточно вместо дефиса поставить тире, ведь это разные знаки: "Привет воинам **—** освободителям от немецко-фашистских захватчиков!"

Comment: Мысль-то хорошоя, в каком доугом контексте я бы согласился на все сто.  
А тут - не поймут-с. Хоть десять тире поставь.

Comment: Мысль замечательная!

Comment: А запятая не годится? Тут же обособленное дополнение получается, не? Да и вообще какая изначальная смысловая нагрузка у предложения была? Привет конкретным воинам? И от кого?

Comment: Запятая здесь обозначала бы перечисление, то есть привет воинам и еще освободителям. Кроме того, приложение, носящее пояснительный характер и стоящее в конце предложения, выделяется с помощью тире.

Answer (score 0):

Я посмеялся.  
Можно "от немецко-фашистских захватчиков" переделать в обособленное определение, например: "Привет воинам-освободителям, победивших (одолевших, выгнавших и т.д.) немецко-фашистских захватчиков!"

Comment: Тогда уж победившИМ...

Answer (score 0):

Можно переделать "Приветствуем воинов-освободителей от немецко-фашистских захватчиков!"

Comment: Ага! Еще "передаем привет" можно!