# Как правильно построить фразу?

Tags: стилистика, согласование

Есть такой курьез, когда на транспаранте написали: "Привет воинам-освободителям от немецко-фашистских захватчиков". Звучит так, будто захватчики передают привет.)))
А если серьезно, как можно перестроить эту фразу, чтобы она не звучала так по-дурацки?

Answer (score 2):

Может быть, стоит отказаться от слова "привет", если оно придает двусмысленность выражению. Можно написать так: "Слава воинам-освободителям от немецко-фашистских захватчиков".

Comment: Если оставить слово "привет", то можно написать так: "Привет воинам-освободителям, победившим немецкий фашизм.

Answer (score 0):

Если написать это предложение правильно, выделив распространенное приложение тире, а не дефисом, то двусмысленность при чтении снимается: Привет воинам - освободителям от немецко-фашистских захватчиков. Но при восприятии фразы на слух курьез сохраняется. Это как призыв "Берегите природу - мать вашу".

Вариант: Привет воинам - победителям фашизма. Другие варианты более громоздкие: Привет воинам, освободившим мир от немецко-фашистских захватчиков; ...разгромившим немецко-фашистских захватчиков и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

"Привет воинам, освободителям от немецко-фашистских захватчиков!" По-моему, это самый короткий вариант, близкий к оригиналу, и без двусмыслия

Answer (score 0):

Привет воинам, освободившим мир от немецко-фашистских захватчиков.

Этот приведённый выше вариант представляется наиболее оптимальным.

Но никак не пример Русака.

Comment: С женщинами, даже если они правы, я могу спорить, даже если я не прав. Но перед @Татьяна Гусарова я пасую, испытывая неловкость, робость и даже смятение. Её железная логика, способная разгибать подковы, присуща, по-моему, только ей одной. Преклоняюсь, став на одно колено

Comment: Я не хотела Вас обидеть, извините. 
Но посмотрите внимательно сами, что получилось. Рядом два однородных члена, и запятая спасительницей (пардон за каламбур) тут не является.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не извиняйтесь. Я ведь просто тренировался в использовании высокого штиля, пыль в глаза пускал. Но если я Вас чем-то задел, примите мои ответные извинения.

Answer (score 0):

[повтор вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13548/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)